# Incorrect edge labels in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I am seeing something weird with the networkx package. Here is a minimal concrete verifiable example.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge('A', 'B', weight=1, title='ab', subtitle='testing')
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'title')
print(edge_labels)
```

This gives the expected output, which is the title attribute of the edge.

```
{('A', 'B'): 'ab'}
```

When I use the edge_labels for plotting,

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, labels=edge_labels)
plt.show()
```

I see the following graph, where all the edge attributes are displayed. I expected only the title to turn up.

[image]

The graph I am constructing is a step-by-step process so the edge labels get updated as more information is processed. How do I label the edges with only the attributes I want at the end of the graph construction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels)
```

instead of

```
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, labels=edge_labels)
```

---

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge('A', 'B', weight=1, title='ab', subtitle='testing')
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'title')
print(edge_labels)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

---

Since the [call signature for `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html) looks like this:

```
draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=None, label_pos=0.5,
    font_size=10, font_color='k', font_family='sans-serif',
    font_weight='normal', alpha=1.0, bbox=None, ax=None, rotate=True, **kwds)
```

the function expects the labels to be supplied by the keyword parameter `edge_labels`. Since the call signature also includes `**kwds`, the bogus parameter `labels` is swallowed silently, and [this piece of code](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_edge_labels)

```
if edge_labels is None:
    labels = dict(((u, v), d) for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True))
```

generated the "strange" label you were seeing in the result.